# VirtualBox Booting from Raw Disk Error

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-11.04

I'm using Ubuntu (11.04) on a triboot machine, and I'm trying to boot the XP partition at /dev/sda1 using VirtualBox.

I've run

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename sda.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda
```

clicked Use existing hard disk in VirtualBox and selected sda.vmdk, but then it throws the following error:

```
Failed to open the hard disk /home/a930913/sda.vmdk.
The medium '/home/a930913/sda.vmdk' can't be used as the requested device type.
```

with details

```
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Medium
Interface: 
IMedium {9edda847-1279-4b0a-9af7-9d66251ccc18}
Callee: 
IVirtualBox {d2de270c-1d4b-4c9e-843f-bbb9b47269ff}
```

Help on booting my XP partition inside Ubuntu please.

EDIT: Turned out it needed to be run as root. Now I get this when I boot it up:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Turned out it needed to be run as root

Run as root is not need, just append self into 'disk' group and relogin.
About error on boot XP: reboot to XP and set 'Standart IDE controller' in device manager 4 u IDE controller, also u can set 'Stadart VGA controller' 4 u videocard (create new hardware profile may be a good idea). In VirtualBox mashine properties enable 'Use IOAPIC' option.

Good luck!

Comment: I didn't find how to set the Device Manager stuff, but ticking the Use IO APIC option did the trick. Thanks!